# Exception Error in the Code

Tags: asp.net

A frequently error is coming in the Code and error message of that error is

```
At least one recipient is required, but none were found
```

and Stack trace of that error is given below .

```
at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) 
at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) 
at MFActivityPlanning.clsCommons.SendEmail(String sToMailAddr, String sSubject, String sMessage, MailFormat format, String sFromMailAddr)
```

pls help me, how can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are passing null or an empty string to the SendMail method for the parameter sToMailAddr.  Alternatively, you may not be adding the recipient email address to the MailMessage object in the SendMail method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: A little code would help.

The Exception says that you need to add a recipient for your mail, so obviously you're either not passing a valid mail address to your `SendEmail` method in the `sToMailAddr` parameter or the mail address is not being assigned to the respective properties before you try to send the mail.

Without code, there's nothing more I can say.

Comment: yes this is in Catch block found exception how can i remove it?

Comment: Smtp.Mail.Send(msg);
this code line generate the exception error line like following 
the transport failed to connect the server

how can i fix it?

Comment: Well, as I said: add a valid mail address to the recipient field of the MailMessage object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if there isn't a value in sToMailAddr, as that would be the recipient.